# Linux doesn't show added group

Tags: linux, permissions, ubuntu-16.04, usergroups

When I try to make my 'devexe' group it says it exists but when I try to see it via this command :

```
$ cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

it's not in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because groups are stored in `/etc/group`
The correct command to list groups: `getent group`

Comment: thanks @ipor
now another question : if a user is in A,B,C,D groups ...
and it creates a file with permission code of 770 , would all users of all those groups (A,B,C,D) have access to this file ?